# myphp.php?x=8&y=8?

Tags: php, javascript

Posted this question:

[If Not A HREF Javascript then what [e.g. mobile phones]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365042/if-not-a-href-javascript-then-what-e-g-mobile-phones)

Using [php]

```
echo "<input type='image' src="someimage.gif" alt='Some Image' onclick='yourFunction()' />";
```

That code is in myphp.php

I call myphp.php.

When I click on the image it executes the javascript function [just an alert to test] and then it places "?x=8&y=8" on the end of myphp.php giving myphp.php?x=8&y=8 [with 8 and 8 seemingly random single digit numbers].

What's going on here? Anything to be concerned about?

Comment: Sorry should be:

echo "<TD><INPUT type='image' src='edit.png' alt='Change Details' onClick='javascript:edit()'></TD>";

Comment: it's probably coordinates relative to top-left of your image

Comment: @user667925: You can always use the [| edit |](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5366638/edit) link below your question if you want to add something. (We like that here.)

Answer (score 2):

It is sending the coordinates of the image, the exactly the place where the user clicked, i don't think you should be concerned about this.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting. 

return false; as a second statement to the onClick prevented it